# vs2012 build fails, though it runs locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a build task in vs2012.

I ran it.

It complains that there are some missing references,

though I see them on my proj and they lead to relative path

(the folder that exists in the source control)

I have ereased the sln locally,

I did `get latest` from the source control and rebuilt it.

The references were missing. I have fixed it. Re-run the taks and again similar error.

How can it be if the sln builds successfuly on my machine and on a colleage clean machine?

[image]

Comment: Someone else has a different folder structure and is checking it back in to source control?

Comment: It means that compiled build that is working is not from the current revision of the source.  We really can't help with a problem like this, you need to figure out when your project broke, and determine the cause yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to take a guess, it would be one of the following:

1. The missing types are located in one or more assemblies that are either not checked into source control; or
2. Those assemblies are referenced via a path reference that isn't the right path in your source control.
3. Those assemblies aren't part of the normal project structure that would be pulled down by the build server.
4. Those assemblies are gac'd locally and you are referring to gac'd versions instead of the correct ones.
5. It's a web site project and *someone* on your team has those assemblies gac'd or installed in some other directory and they screw up the project every time they check it in. (common in web site projects, highly unusual in web application projects).